# Configurable Map Viewer custom basemap in viewer.js

Tags: dojo, configurable-map-viewer

I have a problem in configuring basemap in viewer.js. I want to use a completely offline basemap for my app. I have read the [instruction here](https://docs.cmv.io/en/latest/configure/mapOptions/) but can't make it work.

Here is what i have tried :

> 1. Modifying the viewer.js in the *define* section

```
define([
     'esri/dijit/Basemap',
           'esri/dijit/BasemapLayer',
           'esri/geometry/Point',
           'esri/units',
           'esri/geometry/Extent',
           'esri/config',
           'esri/tasks/GeometryService',
           'esri/layers/ImageParameters'
        ], function (Basemap, BasemapLayer, Point, units, Extent, 
         esriConfig, GeometryService, ImageParameters)
```

> 2. Adding the custom basemap in viewer.js

```
mapOptions: {
       basemap: new Basemap({
            id: 'mymap',
            layers: [new BasemapLayer({
            url: 'http://10.255.1.99/arcgis/rest/services/mymap/MapServer/'
            })]
        }),
        center: new Point({  
            x: 90.0148634,
            y: -9.5489264,
            spatialReference: {
                wkid: 32750
            }
        }),
        zoom: 5,
        sliderStyle: 'small',
        showAttribution: true
    },
```

Nothing is displayed. How can I correct this ? Am i missing something ?

Note : i am using CMV ver 1.3.4, Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

The X and Y coordinates of your center point look odd for the wkid [32750](https://epsg.io/32750) that you used.  Perhaps you used LAT/LNG instead of X/Y coordinates.

You can use the Esri Sample code [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/map_simple.html) to test your `mapOptions`.